# how I can ignoring safe area on CollectionViewCell

Tags: uicollectionview, uikit, uiimageview, safeareaview

hello I have a problem with UICollectionView
I added one UICollectionView on my storyboard for image slider.

but I couldn't ignore safe area.

how can I do?

[image: my collectionview]

[image: settşbgs]ü

[image: storyboard]

I tried to fix it with constraints but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can set the constraints of the collectionView according to view itself, not the safeArea. [image]